# How to get delayed ajax data to rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, view

I have an api action that takes about 10 seconds to retrieve data.  I use the alert to verify the data is actually there, my question is how to properly send it to a rails view to display.  here is my js snippet

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"pages/splunk_bf_data",
    action:"splunk_bf_data",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
      alert(data);
      splunk_bf_data = data;
    }
  })
```

the slow action is located on a separate page 'pages/splunk_bf_data' so the this page can render quickly.

Comment: Where is the problem exactly? What part are you struggling with?

Comment: My problem is my ignorance, ha.  I'm not quite getting the concept, I'm guessing there must be a div, or variable I can assign to this that I can pass to the rails view, and also a refresh of the page once the data is in..just don't know how to do that or where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Fine..Now you have your data in the success callback. Now append the data into the html element in the way you want. If you have div like this..

```
<div class="data-container">
<div>
```

And you want to display the data inside the div then,

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"pages/splunk_bf_data",
    action:"splunk_bf_data",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
      var html = '<p>' + data.yourData + '</p>'
      $('.data-container').html(html); //insert the content inside your <div>
    }
  });
```